# HKQueryAnchor per data type, per source, or per source per data type?

Tags: ios, healthkit

I find I need to query HealthKit on a per-source basis to be sure I am receiving all data for a user in a  given category. I cannot find anything in the docs explaining how an HKQueryAnchor object works with respect to querying different sources. In particular, do I need to persist an anchor per source per data type or simply an anchor per data type or simply an anchor per source?

Similarly, how do I compare anchors for the same data type but a different data source. Is there a meaningful comparison?

I'd like to persist my 'bookmark' for each data type and source so I am not receiving duplicates from Health Kit.

Answer (score 0):

Separate anchors should be persisted for each distinct query you execute.  Queries are distinct if their predicates or their sample types differ.  For instance, queries for "steps from source A" and "steps from source B" are distinct because their predicates differ.  Likewise "active energy burned from source A" and "steps from source A" are distinct because their sample types differ, and you would need to store separate anchors for each.

There is no special relationship between HealthKit sources and anchors - the predicate is what describes your query, regardless of whether your predicate filters by source, date, value, etc.

As a side note: it sounds like you are attempting to execute a separate anchored object query for every source of samples of a particular type.  I think it would be simpler if you just executed a single query for all samples of the sample type, and then processed the samples separately based on their source (by looking at the `source` property of each `HKSample`).  Then you would only need to persist one anchor for the sample type.

Comment: how do I do that? My understanding is that if I query for a particular sample type, the returned data will ONLY be from the highest priority source for this data type. This is what I read and what I saw. For example, if I queried for cycling distance, only the highest priority cycling data source would be returned if I queried all sources .That's why I started querying individual sources....to get all the data.

Comment: What you are referring to is how HKStatisticsQuery handles overlapping samples from different sources.  When you use HKSampleQuery or HKAnchoredObjectQuery, you get all the samples that match predicate.  Have you tried executing a query with no predicate at all?

Comment: if I execute with no predict at all I will also get results from my own app's source. I do not want these duplicate values to enter my data stream. I know empirically that when I submit an NSSet of data sources that include all sources but my own, I only get data back provided from a single source rather than from all the sources for which data is available.

Comment: Why not look at the source property and discard the samples that have your app's source?  That's simpler and more efficient than making multiple queries.  The behavior you describe with providing a set of sources sounds like a bug that you should file with Apple, as that should work correctly for this purpose.

Comment: @Allan when user has quite big amount of data (i.e. steps for 1 year) loading data history is not instant (based on my experiments it may take about 30 seconds or even more). So it would be good to split data loading (i.e. loading data by weeks) so we are able to show progress to the user. Taking that into account I would like to know if it's possible to compare anchors in some way so we could find latest anchor for the whole period based on individual anchors of each sub-period. Or may we assume that anchor of the latest sub-period of a period is the latest anchor of the whole period?